# Doing User Profiles In Django

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to set up user profiles in my site so we have:

> www.example.com/someuser
>
> www.example.com/anotheruser2

in my urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<profile>[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,36})/',    'site.views.profile),
```

and my view:

```
def profile(request, profile):
    ... do something ...
```

There are two questions:

1. Is this the correct way to do this or is there a better way?
2. How should I handle other urls, like "aboutus", etc.

For Point 2, I would do:

```
url(r'^aboutus/',    'site.views.aboutus'),
url(r'^(?P<profile>[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,36})/',    'site.views.profile),
```

So now profile will be the catchall for everything else in the site, and I have to check for a valid profile then throw a 404 if a password is not found.

Again, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good idea to use `site.views.profile` as a catchall. It's not good separation of responsibilities, it shouldn't be its job. How about something like this instead:

```
url(r'^profile/$', 'site.views.profile_self'),
url(r'^profile/(?P<profile_name>[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,36})/$', 'site.views.profile'),
url(r'^aboutus/', 'site.views.aboutus'),
```

For the catchall, use a custom 404 page, or you could let the server raise a 404 error.

Comment: The problem I see w/ this solution is I would have to set up www.example.com/profile/someuser   The requirement is www.example.com/someuser

Comment: If that's a *hard requirement* then you don't have a choice, other than do as you proposed. But it's poor design, as it prevents you from properly separating responsibilities.

Answer (score 0):

**accounts/models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class User():
    def get_profile(self):
        return UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user_id=self.id)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    # another fields
```

**accounts/urls.py**

```
url(r'^profile/$', 'site.views.profile'),
```

**accounts/views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def profile(request):
    # get current logged user profile
    profile = request.user.get_profile()
```

this way the user logged only can see his own profile.

and for the point 2, what's wrong with this?

```
url(r'^about_us/$', 'site.views.about_us'),
```

**--UPDATE--**

ah, ok. then, you are right. but why not with the username?

**accounts/urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w]+)/$', 'site.views.profile'),
```

Comment: The problem I see w/ this solution is I would have to set up www.example.com/profile/someuser The requirement is www.example.com/someuser