# Routing user profiles at the URL hierarchy root

Tags: django

Facebook, GitHub, and Twitter all place user profile URLs at the root of their URL hierarchies, e.g., `http://twitter.com/jack`.

This must be done so that other "system" URLs, like `http://twitter.com/search` are resolved first, so a user named @search can't hijack part of the site.

And if no system URL exists, and no such user profile is found, they must throw a 404.

What's the best way to achieve this using Django's URL routing? My current solution is:

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  # etc, ..., then this last:
  url(r'^(?P<username>.+)$', views.view_profile),
]

def view_profile(request, username):
  try:
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
  except User.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404('User does not exist')
  return HttpResponse(username + ' exists!')
```

In this way, the `view_profile` view is a catch-all for any URL that isn't handled elsewhere. However, it doesn't seem ideal that it is responsible for throwing a 404 exception if no user exists, I'd rather raise some "wrong route" signal that tells Django's URL router to resume attempting to route the request. This way the 404 is generated by Django the same way as if I did not have the catch-all route.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537179/doing-user-profiles-in-django) asks essentially the same thing, but the solutions involved creating a subpath for the user profile.

Comment: Well that's not really how Django routing works. Django resolves the URL first, then calls the relevant view; you can't tell it to "resume" routing from a view because that phase has already completed by then.

Comment: In your example, `view_profile` will have to be a catch-all if you want your user profile urls to be at the root level - there's no way around it. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24539162/4593972) you posted is as close as you can get to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually recommend a more RESTfull way of addressing the users profile. A nice organisation or a users profile rout would be `/users/{pk}/` or if you want it easier for the client (we are doing it like that) `/users/me/` so the client doesn't need to rememer it's id and the user is choosen from the session or auth/bearer token or whatever authorisation system you prefer.